# jQuery Object Selector Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using the following code:

```
            $("#DialogTable select.select-button-dropdown").each(function(t) {

                //Get the options of this select

            });
```

to get all selects from within my table.

I want to be able to pull the options from each select.

I would usually do try `$('#selectid option")` and that would return them but i can't.

How do i do that because `$(t,"option")` doesnt work ?

Could someone explain how selectors work when i have already got my object e.g t?

Comment: `$(this).find('option')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$("#DialogTable select.select-button-dropdown").each(function(t) {
    $(this).find('option'); //gets all option
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("option",this)` in your each callback

Alternatively -

`$(this).find('option')`

Comment: Whats the benfit of this and not using find like below +1 for quick answer

Comment: @LmC none as .find() is faster but something you will never notice except you have thousand options. PXL just show you the right syntax to use context